# How can i use arrays in Highcarts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two arrays in my code and i would like to plot some data on a Pie chart using Highcharts. One arrays contains the labels of that data, and the other one contains the data. Here is what i tried:

```
arr1 = [10, 39, 30]
arr2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']


Highcharts.chart('container-2', {
  chart: {
    margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    spacingTop: 0,
    spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0,
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Example'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      size: '50%',
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Balances',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: {
        y: arr1,
        name: arr2,
    }
  }]
});
```

Unfortunately that generates a chart without any data on it. Can someone help me find what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the data from labels and data `arrays` in array of objects with **`y`** and **`name`** as properties.

```js
const arr1 = [10, 39, 30];
const arr2 = ["one", "two", "three"];

const pieData = arr1.map((cur, index) => {
  return { name: arr2[index], y: cur };
});

console.info("PIEDATA::", pieData);
```

Then pass on this formatted data to the series data:

```
//notice data should be an array of objects for those pie plotting values
    series: [{
        name: 'Balances',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data:pieData
      }]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Tried this but the chart div is blank, trying to debug to see what's wrong

Comment: @Jack022 Just had this on a plunker and ..works fine [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/evGVfkrIEkcx4x7Frhy1?p=preview). Make sure u're giving correct `id` to the chart to draw upon.

Answer (score 1):

`y` and `name` should be single values. You will have to convert the two arrays into an Object directly:

```
let data = {}
for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    data[arr2[i]] = data[arr1[i]];
}
```

Then in the chart options:

```
Highcharts.chart('container-2', {
    ...
    series: [{
        name: 'Balances',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: data
    }]
});
```

Comment: Tried this, i'm getting still a blank chart, but i think i understand why: i tried to console.log(data) and i get something like this: {'one': undefined}. For some reason the numbers from arr1 are undefined, trying to find why

Comment: I see. Well see if the arrays are being generated properly and just plug them into the chart.